# Query last day, last week, last month SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, datetime

I have this table in my Android SQLite DB:

```
CREATE TABLE statistics (subject TEXT, hits INTEGER, fails INTEGER, date DATE)
```

On `date` field is stored `datetime('now', 'localtime')` in every register.

Now I must query last day, last week and last month registers for showing some statistics.
I've been trying something like this

```
    SELECT Timestamp, datetime('now', '-1 week') FROM statistics WHERE TimeStamp < datetime('now', '-1 week')
```

and this

```
    SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', localtime') AND datetime ( 'now', '-1 month')
```

and doesn't work :(

How can I do it?

Can I check if the query is OK by simply forwarding date in the virtual device emulator?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint.  The last day of the month is -1 from the first day of the next month.

Comment: Thank you @JonH. I have found a solution, but I cannot post it for the time being. In some hours all of you will have it :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have found this solution. I hope it works for you.

For last day:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

For last week:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', '-6 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

For last month:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: `-6 days` without the space! Can't edit it, it says edit must be at least 6 characters

Comment: In sqlite 3.9.1 at least, a missing `'localtime'` between `'now', 'start...'` may cause unexpected behavior. They should be `datetime('now', 'localtime', 'start of day')` as an example.

Answer (score 10):

This code should get you the previous month

```
SELECT * 
FROM statistics 
WHERE date >= date('now','start of month','-1 month')
AND date < date('now','start of month')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM statistics 
WHERE date >= date('now','start of month','-1 months')
AND date < date('now','start of month')
```

On more months, is **"months"** and not **month** like as other said before.

Answer (score 0):

This code will bring previous week records hopefully

```
SELECT  * FROM  order_master
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',om_date) >= date('now','-14 days') AND 
strftime('%Y-%m-%d',om_date)<=date('now') order by om_date LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Previous week or previous *two* weeks?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
max(date(date, 'weekday 0', '-7 day')) WeekStart,
max(date(date, 'weekday 0', '-1 day')) WeekEnd,date 
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calendar and then get the timestamp from it

```
final Calendar todayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final long todayTimestamp = todayCalendar.getTime().getTime();
todayCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
final long aWeekAgoTimestamp = todayCalendar.getTime().getTime();
final String selection = TABLE_COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " BETWEEN " + aWeekAgoTimestamp + " AND " + todayTimestamp;
```