# SQLite Last month

Tags: sqlite, spiceworks

I am trying to create a report in spiceworks that requires the previous month's data.  I saw this link here: [Query last day, last week, last month SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504218/query-last-day-last-week-last-month-sqlite) however the month example only returns the current month.  I need the previous month.  The report will be ran on the first of each month and here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT a.id as "Ticket #", c.first_name||' '|| c.last_name as "Created By", a.c_location as "Location", 
   a.c_hud as "HUD", a.closed_at as "Closed", a.c_urgency as "Urgency", a.category as "Category", 
   a.summary as "Summary", SUM(b.time_spent)/3600.0 as "Time Spent (Hrs)", 
   d.price*d.quantity as "Purchases" 
FROM tickets a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work b ON a.id = b.ticket_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_list_items d on a.id = d.ticket_id
JOIN users c ON a.created_by = c.id
WHERE closed_at BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now','localtime')
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY c_location;
```

Once I have it pull the correct data set, I have to convert the the total b.time_spent field which is integer type, into an hours format. So if the time spent sums to be 33600, I would need the output to be converted to 9.33, vice the 9 that its currently given. It's currently only giving me Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: sql statement includes CLs suggestion to fix the decimal issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a floating-point division, at least one of the numbers must be a floating-point number.
Use:

```
SUM(b.time_spent) / 3600.0
```