# Search data by week,month year and date

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE Income (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT, amount DOUBLE, sdate DATE, way TEXT,desc TEXT)
```

And after that i want to search date sort by sdate column

this is my query but no out put from this query.

```
SELECT * from Income where sdate=DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
```

Comment: What I did for similar search in my app is I added another column with value as `YearMonthDay`, e.g; Today would be `20160301`. Now its easier to  retrieve entries > this week's start date, this month, year (`20160101`) and use between for range. Let me know if you need more information with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a suggestion :

**CHANGE sdate to TEXT**

queries i have tried and got results accordingly;

```
SELECT * FROM Income WHERE sdate BETWEEN date('now', '-6 days') AND date('now', 'localtime');

SELECT * FROM Income WHERE sdate >= date('now', 'start of month') AND sdate <= date('now', 'localtime');
```

you can also use static date:

```
SELECT * FROM Income WHERE sdate >= '2016-02-01' and sdate <= '2016-03-01';
```

similarly all three given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504218/query-last-day-last-week-last-month-sqlite) answer on stackoverflow.

Now, once you get this day, week, month you can **use this variable to generate final query by using AND clause**.

If you want to simply use sorted order by date than

```
SELECT * FROM Income WHERE sdate BETWEEN date('now', '-6 days') AND date('now', 'localtime') ORDER by sdate;
```

Thus, you can get result as you want.