# sqLite database -next week, next Month query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sql

I am kind of stuck in a place. I want to **load data from my SQLite database in android by next week, next month**, etc. But couldn't do it **although I have tried last week and last month's query, which was working fine.** It would be helpful if someone can assist me with the query.

For last week and last month the query I used from the following answer and which was working fine.
[Query last day, last week, last month SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504218/query-last-day-last-week-last-month-sqlite)

But if I want to load data for next week and next month then what will be the query?
I have tried the following queries but wasn't working.

```
SELECT  *  FROM AT_ActivityTrackerEntry   WHERE AT_ActivityTrackerEntry.DeadlineDate BETWEEN datetime('now', '6 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')  limit 10 

SELECT  *  FROM AT_ActivityTrackerEntry   WHERE AT_ActivityTrackerEntry.DeadlineDate BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime') AND datetime('now', '+6 days')  limit 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st query:

```
SELECT * FROM AT_ActivityTrackerEntry   
WHERE AT_ActivityTrackerEntry.DeadlineDate 
      BETWEEN datetime('now', '6 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')  
limit 10
```

is wrong because `datetime('now', '6 days')` is greater than `datetime('now', 'localtime')`, so `BETWEEN` fails and you get no results.

The 2nd query:

```
SELECT * FROM AT_ActivityTrackerEntry   
WHERE AT_ActivityTrackerEntry.DeadlineDate 
      BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime') AND datetime('now', '+6 days')  
limit 10
```

should return correct results, although you should use (or not) the modifier `'localtime'` in both cases:

```
BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime') AND datetime('now', 'localtime', '+6 days')
```

and maybe instead of `6` you should add `7` days.

Also for the next month starting from now you can do:

```
BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime') AND datetime('now', 'localtime', '+1 month')
```

Note that `limit` without an `ORDER BY` clause is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked and implemented your solutions and fortunately, it worked perfectly. Thanks for your answer. I am accepting it as the correct answer.